# hudson severe collision detected

Tags: ant, hudson, command, prompt

Iam working on server where hudson sits and i run it thru command prompt, when am working with old credentials(for logging into server not for hudson) i didn't exit hudson,and admin shutdown the server, when my admin changed the credentials to log into with server with my new account credentials (previously am logging with some other account credentials), i logged with new credentials and restarted the hudson server using command prompt but in the command console the hudson is giving the error as
"SEVERE: COLLISION DETECTED timestamp='122324..', expected='111...'" 
 But its running the projects, building it but its status is not shown in the command console,
is this as hudson is treating as two users?
whats the error, and how it can be solved?
please help me out, and please excuse me for my bad explanation.

thanku.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are running two instances of Hudson on the same box (maybe as different users).

It is more a Server Administration issue (Windows or Unix) than a Hudson problem.